# How do WS libraries handle malformed JSON?

Tags: json, node.js, websocket

A client cuts off their controlled connection to your server and reconnects themselves, now in control of the data being sent. If you handle data as JSON (as most WS libraries appear to), how then would you handle malformed JSON? That is, you're sent a string that isn't valid JSON, which must cause an error. In Node.js, for instance, such an error would be fatal.

How then do WS libraries handle this problem? I've searched and searched, looked up Socket.IO's source, and just can't find where this problem is dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

The WebSocket itself [only support UTF8 text or binary data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), so as far the WS is concerned, as long it is a complete message with all its frames, it won't throw any exception. Once you have the text, probably `JSON.parse` is used to create the deserialized object graph, because most browsers have [native support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON), so probably that method will throw an exception explaining the problem.

Comment: I know to use JSON.parse, but the question is how do WS implementations handle malformed JSON: a client sends invalid JSON and crashes your server when you try to parse it. How would that generally be prevented?

Comment: WebSocket knows nothing about JSON, I think you are talking specifically about how Socket.IO handles invalid JSON, right?

Comment: How any WS library handles invalid JSON, as the problem posed in the content of the question indicates. Updated title for further clarity, though.

Comment: If I create a library that handles invalid JSON by sending a team of highly trained monkeys to the user, is that a valid answer?

Comment: Simply close the WebSocket connection with an appropriate (error) closing code/message.